# How do I center a column of images vertically, responsively for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm coding up an app that displays 9 newest photos having certain tag. I solved the problem of different image sizes by setting every picture's size to 240px wide and 200px tall.

My question is how do I center them vertically so they are in the middle of screens width? I want them to be responsive, so they are always in the middle, no matter the width of the device displaying them.

HTML:-

```
<div id="results" class="row"></div>
```

So far I've tried pretty much everything I could find on the internet. I should mark, that there are 9 photos being displayed, so user will have to scroll. That means that every solution containing position: absolute; won't do it.

Photos are being picked through Flickr API. After that, I .append() them to div#results by doing:-

```
$("#results").append('<div class="miniaturka col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><a href="'+myresult_size.url+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+myresult_size.source+'" ></a></div>');
```

Bootstraps grid fails to center them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Text-align center on parent centers all child elements which are inline.

```css
.miniaturka {
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="results" class="row">
  <div class="miniaturka col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="miniaturka col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How `width: 100vw;` concerns with `col-sm-4` width? class `col-sm-4` means a presence of the same width cells on the left and on the right. If they are empty, that there's no sense to state neither  `width: 100vw;` nor `col-sm-4`.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```html
<div id="results" class="row text-center"></div>
```

or use

```css
#results{
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, none of your proposals worked. Pictures keep their position on the left side of the screen

Answer (score 0):

For cell of 4-wide you need to use offset class `col-sm-offset-4`.
When you define `col-sm-4`, all classes for wider viewports will inherit this definition, I mean `col-sm-4` is equal to `col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4`. Also you need to apply class `text-center` for cell that is wider than its child image.

So result is:

```
$("#results").append('<div class="miniaturka col-xs-12 col-sm-4  col-sm-offset-4 text-center">
    <a href="'+myresult_size.url+'" target="_blank">
       <img src="'+myresult_size.source+'" >
     </a>
    </div>');
```

Here is an example snippet:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 240px;
  max-height: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="miniaturka col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 text-center">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300">
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300">
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im sorry, nothing really changed. Pictures stay at the same positions as before the swap.

Comment: added css rules for `img`. look at changed snippet

Comment: Right now images overflow out of their borders and the borders themselves stick to the left side of the screen

Comment: have you appended css styles? you didn't give any of that in the question. look at jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xet1osha/

Comment: It seems you didn't paste a link to bootstrap.css in your page. `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`